# addEventListener to an array of divs and images, run and pause

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having serious difficulty figuring this one out, so basically, I have been given some HTML code and CSS, which creates a 'book' in an HTML page which turns its pages every 5 seconds or so. My job is only using an external JS page, overwrite the CSS in the easiest way possible to turn the pages at a click. Currently only the first page turns on a click. Have attached relevant details.
My current JS

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    let d = document.querySelector("#page" + i);
    d.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused"
    console.log(d);
    d.addEventListener("click", function () {
        d.style.WebkitAnimationDelay = "0s";
        d.style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
    })
}
```

and the CSS that i've been given:

```
.page {
    transform-origin: top left;

    animation-name: flippage;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

div#page0 { 
    animation-delay: 5s;    
    z-index: 0;
}

img#page1 { 
    animation-delay: 10s;
    z-index: -1;
}

img#page2 {
    animation-delay: 15s;
    z-index: -2;
}
img#page3 {
    animation-delay: 20s;
    z-index: -3;
}
img#page4 {
    animation-delay: 25s;
    z-index: -4;
}

img#page5 {
    animation-delay: 30s;
    z-index: -5;
}

img#page6 {
    animation-delay: 35s;
    z-index: -6;
}

img#page7 {
    animation-delay: 40s;
    z-index: -7;
}

img#page8 {
    animation-delay: 45s;
    z-index: -8;
}

img#page9 {
    animation-delay: 50s;
    z-index: -9;
}

img#page10 {    
    animation-delay: 55s;
    z-index: -10;
}

div#page11 {    
    animation-name: none; /* Don't close the flap at the end */
    /*animation-delay: 60s;*/
    z-index: -11;
}


/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes flippage {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); 
        z-index: 1; 
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg); 
        z-index: 1;
    }
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes flippage {
    from {
        transform: rotateY(0deg); 
        z-index: 1; 
    }
    to {
        transform: rotateY(180deg); 
        z-index: 1; 
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is your actual specific question/ problem?

Comment: Which part does not work? If nothing works, try `webkitAnimationPlayState`, so with a small letter `w`. If only the click does not work, you probably need to add it somewhere where the click will reach the handler. If the clicking works, but the animation does not actually go correctly, you have the problem described here: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/ in the 'manipulating CSS animations' paragraph.

Comment: @Shilly You can link directly to that section: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/#article-header-id-3

Comment: an idea would be to overwrite the animation for all of the divs, then attach the click event, playing with `AnimationPlayState` is very difficult to control, by default all the pages will flip in the end, all you're doing is pausing it, then starting it again on a click of any div, if you want to fix this, you'll have to wait for the page to flip then pause it again and so on.